# gtk_entry_set_input_purpose not recognized

Tags: c, gtk, gtkentry

I found in the doc the function :
[gtk_entry_set_input_purpose()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-input-purpose) to set the input-method of a gtkentry,
but when using it, gcc didn't recognize it,  it gives me this error

```
implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_entry_set_input_purpose’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
undefined reference to `gtk_entry_set_input_purpose'
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Did you `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`?

Comment: of course , and all other function work correctly !

Comment: can you test the function for me ,
if you have codeblocks && gtk+,

Comment: Which version of Gtk+ are you working with?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of GTK installed on your system? `gtk_entry_set_input_purpose` was introduced in GTK+ 3.6, and if you have headers for an older version lying around, the compiler can pick up those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it was a linking problem , 
compiled successfully with windows after linking all libs ,